# What's the Correct Way to Run Code After Event Handlers?

Tags: events, event-handling, gtk#

I am deriving a class from `Gtk.Button` that is supposed to run some code when the button is clicked, but only *after* the user-defined event handlers.

Based on .NET conventions, this wouldn't be a problem. The following exemplary Windows Forms code shows a subclass of `System.Windows.Forms.Button` that executes some code *before* the event handlers, then invokes the event handlers (by calling the inherited [`OnClick` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onclick.aspx); the same would work in WPF with [`System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.onclick.aspx)), and then executes some code *after* the event handlers:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ButtonClickedTestSWF
{
    class Program
    {
        private class MyButton : Button
        {
            protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("before");
                base.OnClick(e);
                Console.WriteLine("after");
            }
        }

        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Form win = new Form() {
                    Text = "Test"
                   }) {
                win.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
                win.Size = new Size(300, 200);

                MyButton btn = new MyButton();
                btn.Text = "Button";
                btn.Click += delegate {
                    Console.WriteLine("event");
                };
                btn.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                btn.Parent = win;

                Application.Run(win);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As expected, the output is:

```
before
event
after
```

---

However, I have so far failed to replicate this behaviour in Gtk#. Contrary to .NET conventions, the inherited [`OnClicked` method of `Gtk.Button`](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=M%3aGtk.Button.OnClicked%28%29) does not seem to fire the [`Clicked` event](http://docs.go-mono.com/monodoc.ashx?link=M%3aGtk.Button.Clicked). In fact, the docs call the `OnClicked` method a "default handler".

To verify that Gtk# behaves differently, here's some sample code:

```
using System;

using Gtk;

namespace ButtonClickedTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private class MyButton : Button
        {
            public MyButton()
            {
            }

            public MyButton(IntPtr raw) : base(raw)
            {
            }

            protected override void OnClicked()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("before");
                base.OnClicked();
                Console.WriteLine("after");
            }
        }

        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.Init();

            using (Window win = new Window("Test")) {
                win.WindowPosition = WindowPosition.Center;
                win.SetSizeRequest(300, 200);
                win.Hidden += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
                    Application.Quit();
                };

                MyButton btn = new MyButton();
                btn.Add(new Label("Button"));
                btn.Clicked += delegate {
                    Console.WriteLine("event");
                };
                win.Add(btn);

                win.ShowAll();
                Application.Run();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the output is

```
before
after
event
```

i.e. even code at the end of `OnClicked` runs already before the `Clicked` event handlers.

---

My question is: **What is the proper way in Gtk# to execute some code upon an event only *after* the event handlers?**

---

I have found two dissatisfying workarounds so far:

The first is to define a replacement for the `Clicked` event, say, a `Clicking` event (with an according `OnClicking` method that fires the `Clicking` event handlers). I could invoke `OnClicking` in my overridden version of `OnClicked` and thus run code before and after the event handlers as I like. Additionally, any subclasses of my button class could use `OnClicking` in the expected way, i.e. calling `base.OnClicking` when the `Clicking` event handlers should run.

This is not very clean, though, because nothing would prevent users of my button class from registering their event handlers with the original `Clicked` event rather with the new `Clicking` event that is properly embedded into the button's logic. In particular, I could not even modify the API documentation for the inherited `Clicked` event to express there that `Clicked` should not be used and users should turn to `Clicking` instead.

The other workaround works only in this specific case, as there happens to be an [`OnReleased` method](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=M%3aGtk.Button.OnReleased%28%29) that is always executed after the `Clicked` event handlers. I could use that method to insert some code that is guaranteed to run only after any `Clicked` event handlers, but obviously, this solution couldn't be transferred to events that are not conveniently followed by some other events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Gtk+, and hence in Gtk# that's the way it is. `Gtk.Button.OnClicked` is installed as the class handler of the signal. And since this signal is of the *"Run First"* kind, the handler is run before any other callback connected to it.

Using Gtk+ from C you have the `g_signal_connect_after()` that registers a callback to be called *after* the class handler and other callbacks are called, but this doesn't seem to be available to Gtk#.

The easiest way to run code after something has passed is to use and one-time *idle* callback. Yes, it is a bit hackish, but it works for any situation, even not related to Gtk signals:

```
protected override void OnClicked()
{
    Console.WriteLine("before");
    base.OnClicked();
    GLib.Idle.Add(delegate {
                Console.WriteLine("after");
                return false;
            });
}
```

Comment: As no-one seems to know a way that one could call *correct*, this seems to be the best solution. For now, I'm not seeing any drawbacks or catches, so I'll accept this.